# What do these korean workplace titles mean?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning, spoken-korean, korean-to-english, phrases

I'm here to ask a question, what do 실장 and 팀장 mean in a company scale like celebrity agency?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

| Korean | English |
| --- | --- |
| 실장 | General Manager/Department Manager/Head of Corporate Office |
| 부장 | General Manager |
| 차장 | Deputy General Manager |
| 과장 | Manager |
| (팀장) | Office Manager/Team Leader/Head of Team |
| 대리 | Assistant Manager |
| 주임 | Senior Clerk/Senior Staff/Supervisor |
| 사원/직원 | Clerk/Staff |

Many companies have often changed positions with overlapping positions such as "Manager" and "Manager" to "Team Leader."

It's hard to know for sure unless someone is actually working at the company. And also it is not clear because each company has different jobs depending on their positions.

Department Manager(실장) will be involved in all tasks of the agency, and the Team Leader(팀장) will manage one of them.

Answer (score 1):

실장 is a corporate rank, whereas 팀장 is more of a business title. Traditionally, Korean conglomerates do not include the position 실장 in their corporate hierarchy but I've heard of smaller firms, e.g. celebrity agencies as you point, that do. 실장 should fall in somewhere between 차장 and 부장, both a team lead or 팀장 role.

> 사원: Analyst (non-executive)

> 대리: Associate (non-executive)

> 과장: Manager (non-executive)

> 차장: Associate Director (team lead, non-executive)

> 부장: Director (team lead, non-executive)

> 이사/상무보: Vice President (executive)

> 상무: Senior Vice President (department lead, executive)

> 전무: Executive Vice President (department lead, executive)

> 부사장: Senior Executive Vice President (executive)

> 사장: President/CEO (executive)

> 부회장: Vice Chairman (executive)

> 회장: Chairman (executive)